# Checking if sub-sequence with constraints

Tags: string, pattern-matching

Assume we have two strings **s1** and **s2** (of lengths **n**1 and **n2** where **n1>=n2**). Denote the **i** th character of **s1** as **s1[i]**. I want to check whether there is a sub-sequence in **s1** equal to **s2**, where some characters of **s1** with indices **{i1,i2,...,ik}** must be included in that sub-sequence.

For example, take **s1="abcddd"** and **s2="abc"** where the characters with indices **{1,2,4}** (1-indexed) in **s1** must be included in the sub-sequence. Now even though the sub-sequence **"abc"** exists in **s1**, since the 4th character in s1, **"d"** must be included, a sub-sequence of the desired nature cannot be found.

Comment: What language? what have you tried?

Comment: Any language is okay. I just need an efficient algorithm. For small strings I have tried the brute-force approach of constructing all sub-sequences with those special characters included. But obviously this approach is not meaningful for large strings.